# draw images in a layer and align them as a matrix

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

How can I make the images that I call in a for loop in KineticJS to be aligned in a kind of matrix?

The behavior that I want to have is to draw them four by four. I don't know their exact number, since I'm using a database to call their paths, so I just use a for loop.

**EDIT**

I changed the code sample with a fiddle to make things simpler : http://jsfiddle.net/tg8TM/

So I did this test

```
imageObj.onload = function() {
var ligne = 1;
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var img = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 100*i,
        y: 50,
        image:imageObj,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });
    if (img.getX()>stage.getWidth()){ //maybe I should use if (i%4 ===0)
        ligne++;
        img.setX(100* ligne+1);
        img.setY(50 * (ligne+1) );          
        layer.add(img);
        layer.draw();
    }
    else {          
        layer.add(img);
        layer.draw();
    }
};
}
```

Here, the images in the end of the stage should be set to another x,y to be drawn in another "line" (like \n). Instead, the output now is diagonal images. Please help me to figure out how to make it. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw your imageObj in rows/cols within the stage like this:

(untested code alert!)

```
var w=imageObj.width;
var h=imageObj.height;
var nextX=0;
var nextY=0;

for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

    var img=new Kinetic.Image({
        x:nextX,
        y:nextY,
        ...
    });

    nextX+=w;
    if(nextX+w>stage.getWidth()){
        nextX=0;
        nextY+=h;
    }

}
```